# Windows application log to console using boost

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I have `MFC` `windows` application. I would like to create console and log some debug information to it. To create console I use [guicon](https://code.google.com/p/gamegui/source/browse/trunk/app/win32/guitest/guicon.cpp?r=7) . For logging I use boost:

```
boost::log::add_console_log(std::cout, boost::log::keywords::format = ">> %Message%");  
RedirectIOToConsole();
FILE_LOG(logINFO)<<"aaa";
cout<<"bbb";
```

On output I see just `bbb` line. What is wrong with boost logging?

Comment: have you tried swapping the order of lines 1 and 2?

Comment: No, this doesn't help

Comment: Erm I guess that means "yes,  that doesn't help " :)